# Elementary question: distinct elements in a set

Tags: set-theory

I'd like to know the syntax for describing a number of elements in a set, and that each of them are distinct. e.g.

{$x,y,z$} $\in A$

I would like to know how I can succinctly express the following, without having to write it out as such:

$ x \neq y \;\;\;\; x \neq z \;\;\;\; y \neq z$

Comment: "Brevis esse laboro, obscurus fio." (Horace)

Comment: For three elements, $x\neq y\neq z\neq x$ expresses the inequalities in 7 symbols.  For four elements, this linear-string approach takes 15.  For five, it can be done in 21, and in general, for any odd number $n>1$, it can be done in $n(n-1)+1$ symbols (although I suppose you might run into trouble at $n=27$).  Curiously, the OEIS does not (yet) have an entry extending $3,7,15,21$ with both $43$ and $73$ in the proper place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Let $x,y,z,$ be pairwise distinct", is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4):

"Let $x, y, z$ be distinct" is enough.

Comment: Is it? http://mathoverflow.net/a/120688/69696

Answer (score 1):

"Let $\lbrace x,y,z \rbrace$ be a set with exactly three elements."

Answer (score 0):

{x,y,z} $\cong3$ or
|{x,y,z}| $=3$